# In PHP, how can you set a textbox value by clicking text on a page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where users can vote for businesses by choosing a category and typing a business name. When they begin typing, the page predicts the business name in a span below the text box.

I want a user to be able to click one of these predicted names and have the name become the value of the text box for submitting. This will ensure consistently correct business names. Ideally, this will happen without having to submit a form or reload the page.

I've seen lots of mentions of jQuery and AJAX but I'd really rather just use PHP in possible. If I have to use a second programming language, let me know.

I apologize if this question isn't very detailed, but I'm new to PHP and still trying to poke around, and I'm picking up on work done by someone else. Also, I'm not looking for blocks of code as answers. If I know the functions I have to use, I should be able to get the rest myself. Thanks SO!

Comment: if you have any code than post here

Comment: Your use case is not possible without javascript. PHP **can't** do client side DOM manipulation without doing a full page relaod

Comment: You are trying to run with the hare and hunt with the hounds. If you don't want to reload the page you need to use Javascript/AJAX, but if it's possible somehow to do it with PHP then the page needs to be reloaded. You can' have both.

Comment: Ok, so we can establish that I need some kind of Javascript or variant. The code I tried (unsuccessfully) for the link that should perform the action in question is the following (the quoted string is being echoed with PHP):
`"<a href=# onclick='document.getElementById('buss').value = ".$name."'>".$name."</a>"`
'buss' is the id of the textbox where I want the name to appear when the link is clicked. $name is the variable containing the name of the business that was predicted.

EDIT: If this needs to be a separate question, let me know!

Answer (score -1):

You need some form of JavaScript manipulation for this. It cant be done in PHP alone.